# In React development, compile and vscode lint settings do not match

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

We are doing front-end development using TypeScript and React.
We are implementing nx as project management and creating the above front part as one project.
I have installed @emotion/react as styling, but I am getting an error regarding this.

### Error Message

```
Type '{ children: Element; css: SerializedStyles; }' cannot be assigned to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'css' does not exist for type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'. ts(2322)
```

The error is not displayed when compiling, but only in vscode's lint.
The compilation passes by adding the following text to tsconfig.json as a solution to the error message, and since it continues to be displayed in vscode, we think there may be a difference in the tsconfig.json that is being read.

```js
    "types": ["@emotion/react/types/css-prop"]
```

The development does not stop because the compilation passes, but I would like to improve it because errors from unnecessary lint are displayed and the development efficiency is reduced.

#### Code

```
<div css={rootStyle}>{props.children}</div>
```

I tried restarting the development node container and restarting vscode, but no improvement.

#### Environments

- docker：4.21.1
- vscode：1.80.0
- Dev Container：0.299.0
- react：18.2.0
- @emotion/react：11.11.1

If anyone knows a solution, please let me know.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

By regenerating the nx workspace and porting the existing code, the error no longer occurs in vscode.
It is possible that some part of the nx workspace was corrupted because it was created in a bad network environment.
Thank you!